# Ceasar Cypher would not count spaces

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program with 4 different functions where one asks the user if they want to encode/decode, another to have an input of the string in a dynamic memory, the actual decryption function, and the output function. I did everything, but the only problem I am having is considering if there is a space within the inputted words.

In my decryption function, I wrote that if the index of the word given has a space, then it would continue and skip that index. EDITED: I have now included the input function and the output function that reads the word and encrypt it.

```
string *input(){
  string *temp = new string;
  cout<<"What is the word: ";
  getline(cin, *temp);
  cin >> *temp;
  return temp;
}
string output(string *in){
  string cypher;
  cypher = decryption(*in);
  cout<<"Result: "<<cypher<<endl;
  return cypher;
}

string decryption(string in){
  int inputSize = in.size();
  int index = 0;
  while(index != inputSize){
    if(in[index] == ' '){//possibly something wrong with this if statement
      index++;
    }else if(in[index] >= 97 && in[index] <= 109){
      in[index]= in[index]+13;
    }else if(in[index] >=110 && in[index] <=122){
      in[index] = in[index]-13;
    }else if(in[index] >=65 && in[index] <=77){
      in[index] = in[index]+13;
    }else if(in[index] >=78 && in[index] <=90){
      in[index] = in[index]-13;
    }
    index++;
  }
  return in;
}
```

Expected outcome: 
Enter 'e' or 'd' to encode or decode. Other keys to exit: e
What is the word: alphabet
Result: nycunorg

Enter 'e' or 'd' to encode or decode. Other keys to exit: e
What is the word: TAF VF
Result: GNS IS

My outcome thus far:
Enter 'e' or 'd' to encode or decode. Other keys to exit: e
What is the word: TAF VF
Result: GNS

Comment: I suspect the problem is where you read the input string in the first place. You stop reading at the first space, and are encoding `TAF`, not `TAF VF`. Show the code that reads user input and calls `decryption`

Comment: The fastest route to an answer might be to compare your encryption and decryption functions to see where they differ.

Comment: `in[index] >= 97 && in[index] <= 109` -- Instead of numbers, it is more clear if you used the actual character.  Example: `in[index] >= 'a' && in[index] <= 'm'`.

Comment: In any event, your expected outcome and outcome thus far are largely meaningless because they are generated by code we don't see. A better [mcve] would include a `main` function with no user input. Just output the result of a call to `decryption("TAF VF")`. Simple demonstration of the problem case.

Comment: Off-topic, but the decryption calculation of the character seems to be able to be accomplished using one or two-line remainder (modulo) arithmetic, not a succession of additions and subtractions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i have put my input and output functions and all the input function does is to get the word(s) that the user inputs. The output function is the one that cyphers the word...I have also dropped the if statement in the beginning but nothing has change :(

Comment: Why are you calling `new` for a `std::string`?  Just use `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i am suppose to read a string and put it to dynamic memory

Comment: I guess no one in your class asked "why do you need to do that".  It's amazing the ridiculous ways teachers want C++ students to put `new` in their code.

Comment: `cin >> *temp` stops reading at the first whitespace character. If you print `*temp` immediately afterwards, you'll find that its value is `TAF`, not `TAF VF`.

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter a space, you effectively increment `index` twice - once in that `if` clause, and again at the end of the loop. This has the net effect of skipping (leaving unencoded) the character that follows the space.

Simply drop the whole `if(in[index] == ' ')` clause. The remaining code already leaves unchanged any character that doesn't fall into the four specially-checked ranges - including space.